# Relationship between eigenvectors of correlation and covariance matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, data-analysis, svd

For the purpose of computing principal components of a dataset, represented as matrix $X$ of dimensions $n \times p$ with $n$ samples and $p$ features, we can compute sample covariance matrix $S$, and compute its eigenvalue decomposition:
$$
    S = Q^t D Q
$$
The principal components are then given by $Z = X \cdot Q$.

An alternative method is to use sample correlation matrix: $\hat{S} = \sigma^{-1} S \sigma^{-1} $, where $\sigma = \mathrm{diag}\left(\sigma_1, \cdots, \sigma_p\right)$ is the diagonal matrix of sample standard deviations:
$$
    \hat{S} = \hat{Q}^t \hat{D} \hat{Q}
$$
The resulting principal components $\hat{Z} = X \cdot \hat{Q}$ are different, but span the same vector space, hence there exists a matrix $T$, such that $Z = \hat{Z} \cdot T$.

For reasons of numerical stability it is preferred to work with the correlation matrix.

I was wondering if it is possible to use $\sigma$, $\hat{D}$ and $\hat{Q}$ to compute $Q$, and avoid doing the eigenvalue decomposition of $S$ recombined from $\sigma$, $\hat{D}$ and $\hat{Q}$ ?

Comment: Did you find out an answer to this? If so, could you answer your own question?

Comment: @Sasha The $X$ in the first PC expression $Z = X Q$ are centered but not scaled to unit variance. Wouldn't the $X$ in the second PC expression $\hat{Z} = X \hat{Q}$ have to be both centered and scaled, such that it should be distinguished from the first $X$?